# ss_domain parameter in context of OAUTH or OpenID?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, single-sign-on, openid-connect, openid

I'm trying to learn about OAUTH and OpenID Connect.

Thus I am investigating my own traffic, listening to Authorization Requests and Grants by checking for **required** parameters in OAUTH as described in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1 and https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.2 for the Authorization Code Flow as well as described in section 4.2.1 and 4.2.2 for the Implicit Flow.

Unfortunately, by using the SSO option for Google on joinhoney.com, I am only able to catch the Request, but not the Authorization Grant.

So, while debugging and having a look at the actual request, I can see the following parameters in the query part of the url:

| Parameter | Value |
| --- | --- |
| redirect_uri | storagerelay://https/www.joinhoney.com?id=auth[censoredID] |
| response_type | permission id_token |
| scope | email profile openid |
| openid.realm |  |
| client_id | 705229005811-2fdpup66d8aefq4qs2ru1n8qiosuq4fb.apps.googleusercontent.com |
| ss_domain | https://www.joinhoney.com |
| fetch_basic_profile | true |
| gsiwebsdk | 2 |

Now, to get to the actual question:

*Where can I find some specified information about the **ss_domain** parameter?*

I could not find any information in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749 as well as on https://openid.net/, however when using google, I can find some people using the ss_domain parameter (only without further explanation), so I doubt it is something only used by joinhoney.com.

Would be happy if somebody could bring some light in here!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are at [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), and you your redirect_uri is to a **different domain** e.g. subdomain.example.com, you need to set ss_domain to https://subdomain.example.com.

This custom ss_domain change, however, is not possible using the Google login client side sdk. You got to push the url manually.

Comment: It is already a bit helpful. I'd still really appreciate a kind of documentation about this.

Anyway - thank you for your answer!

Comment: don't think it's documented anywhere. why not try it and see whether it's like what i said?

Comment: As I'm creating an browser extension detecting OAuth, including scientific documentation and reference. Now I noticed this stuff exists which I also need to include in my algorithm, which needs to be documented and referenced.
It's not about making OAuth work in a specific case.
Thanks for your interest!

Comment: ic. just so u know, i don't think google oauth  redirect will not work without ss_domain.